# Opening port in Packet Filter in Windows 2008 not working

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, port

I am trying to open port 22 so I can do SFTP on my Windows 2008 server (A 1&1 dedicated server.)

The server uses a Packet Filter within Local Security Policy to handle this. I added a rule for port 22 but the port is not open. If I unassign the packet filter, the port does open, and reassigning closes it, so I believe I am in the right area.

I made sure the rule is exactly the same as the others that are there and working (like FTP and Remote Desktop.)

Obviously I am missing something. Any clues?

Thanks, Brad

Answer (score 0):

Finally spotted what I was doing wrong. The destination address was  instead of .

It works now.

- Brad